# DELETE row entry from database

Tags: php, mysql

Good day!
I am totally new to PHP and would appreciate any help coming from you.

I want to delete a row in a database but I got this error:

`Warning: Illegal string offset 'text' in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\deletejoke\jokes.php on line 14`

The code seem okay but I don't know why I'm getting this error.Please guide me to this, thanks a lot!
Please see below the code for your reference:

```
if (isset($_GET['deletejoke'])) {
    try {
        $sql = 'DELETE FROM joke WHERE id = :id';
        $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $s->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id']);
        $s->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error = 'Error deleting joke' . $e->getMessage();
        include 'error.php';
        exit();
    }
        header('Location: .');
        exit();
}

try {
    $sql = 'SELECT id, joketext FROM joke';
    $result = $pdo->query($sql);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $error = 'Error fetching jokes' . $e->getMessage();
    include 'error.php';
    exit();
}
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $jokes = array('id' => $row['id'], 'text' => $row['joketext']);
    }
    include 'jokes.php';
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Exercise #3: Display contents from database</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="?addjoke">Add your own joke!</a>
    <p>Here are all the jokes in the database:</p>
    <?php foreach($jokes as $joke): ?>
    <form action="?deletejoke" method="post">
        <blockquote>
            <p>
                <?php echo htmlspecialchars($joke['text'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $joke['id']; ?>">
                <input type="submit" value="Delete">
            </p>
        </blockquote>
    </form>     
    <?php endforeach; ?>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay. So... which one was line 14 again?

Comment: Yeh according to that.... line 14 is `}` lol

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams "}"

Comment: Sorry for that sir, how do I put line numbers on this post?
Anyways, I'll just highlight line 14:

`<?php echo htmlspecialchars($joke['text'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>`

Thanks!

Comment: I already figured out the error. It's just a typo on the loop.  I used `$jokes = array(...)` instead of `$jokes[] = array(...)` Thanks for your comment and to the 2 answers below. (To @Sean and to the other guy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Warning` is telling you that it is treating `$jokes`, and therefore `$joke` as a string and not an array.

Try building your `$jokes` array like this

```
// initialize the array
$jokes = array();

foreach ($result as $row) {

    // add to the array using $jokes[]
    $jokes[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'text' => $row['joketext']); 
}
```

Comment: Sorry for that sir, I already updated my post. Thanks for that.

Comment: I have deleted the part about `$joke['name']` & `$joke['email']`, but left the original part of my answer, as it can still address your issue.

Comment: I tried putting `$jokes = array();` above `foreach ($result as $row)` but I get the same result/error.

Comment: Did you also do `$jokes[] = array(...)` (adding the `[]` to `$jokes`)?

Comment: You could also check your `$joke` type/data/value by using `var_dump()` -> `<?php foreach($jokes as $joke): var_dump($joke); ?>`. This will be able to tell you if `$joke` is an array or a string, and if there is a key of `text`.

Comment: "Did you also do $jokes[] = array(...) (adding the [] to $jokes)? " This one works for me, thanks!